# Potential issues with SharePoint 2007 and SQL Server default collation?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, configuration, sql

SharePoint installation guidance specifies that SQL Server collation should be set to Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS (case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, Kana-sensitive, and width-sensitive).  However, our internal hosting group uses the default SQL Server 2005 collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  What are the potential issues we might face with MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 2):

The server collation must be configured for case-insensitive, which is ok in your case.

If you use SharePoint itself to create its different databases, it will set the required collation automatically. However, if you use precreated databases - make sure you to change the collation manually. Otherwise, SharePoint won't even let you use those databases.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, does your company do anything in non-english?

Comment: Yes, some of our clients are in Canada, so we support English and French.